# Combine two relationships in one query in Laravel

Tags: laravel

One of my models contains the following:

```
public function from()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Station::class, 'from_station_id');
}

public function to()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Station::class, 'to_station_id');
}
```

In order to use this I'm using the `with('to', 'from')` method. Which results in the following:

> select * from "stations" where "stations"."id" in ('1')
>
> select * from "stations" where "stations"."id" in ('2')

Two cached queries one for "to's" and one for "from's". At the moment with 1 record they are "useful". But in the future they will have a lot of duplicate IDs..

Does Laravel offer an option to combine these?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you'll need to access them from the model by the relation, like `$model->from->first()` or `$model->to->count()`, your best option would be to stick with 2 queries. A query with **where in** clause is not that heavy and you can additionally cache them to speed up.

Comment: Isn't that the situation I have now? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Yep, like I suggest _your best option would be to stick with 2 queries_.